# Wordpress search form with Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a form to search posts in my blog, but my search returns posts from other blog (domain.com/) instead of (domain.com/myblog), yes is a multisite wordpress. i tried everything, follows my code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right searchform" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="s" id="s" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Programs" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
    </div>
    <a id="searchsubmit" type="submit" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also post what's rendered? The actual form after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: A list of plugins that might affect search and queries in general would be helpful. Are you using a custom theme or a stock theme?

Comment: @Sina Yes.
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right searchform" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://sites.medicina.ufmg.br/radio/">

Comment: @ojrask Im using a custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this problem by adding the following code in functions.php

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query)
{
    $parent_categories = ('myblog');
    // you can search by slug or insert the category id directly. your choice
    $cat_term_id = get_category_by_slug($parent_categories)->term_id;

    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_search()) 
        $query->set('cat', $cat_term_id);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <form class="ms-global-search_form" method="get" action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/myblog/'; ?>">
            <input id="s" class="field" name="mssearch" type="text" placeholder="Search across network sites:" size="16" tabindex="1" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="button submit" value="<?php _e( 'Search', 'ms-global-search' )?>" tabindex="2" />
        </form>
```